# shell scripting - multiple equality tests in one if statement

Tags: shell-script, shell, test

So I create a script and it works perfect except at the end when I type in a beverage it executes a line its not suppose to.  The Last line is only suppose to come up when I type "no" or "No"...What did I do wrong?

```
echo -n "Are you thirsty?"
read th

if [ "$th" = "yes" ] || [ "Yes" ]; then
    echo "What would you like to drink?"
    read th
fi

if [ "$th" = "water" ]; then
    echo "Clear crisp and refreshing."
elif [ "$th" = "beer" ]; then
    echo "Let me see some ID."
elif [ "$th" = "wine" ]; then
    echo "One box or Two?"
else
    echo "Coming right up."
fi

if [ "$th" = "no" ] || [ "No" ]; then
    echo "Come back when you are thirsty."
fi
```

Comment: So it's executing the last if statement (the one with no) regardless of your input?

Comment: yes, if i type in beer, it gives the echo for it and the "come back when you are thirsty" at the same time

Comment: I recommend including the "no" option as an else block in the first if statement.

Comment: let me try that out

Comment: so i did that and now when I ask are you thirsty and I type no, it still asks me what would I like to drink

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that `[ "Yes" ]` and `[ "No" ]` are equivalent to `[ -n "Yes" ]` and `[ -n "No" ]` and therefore always evaluate to true.

The proper syntax would be:

```
if [ "$th" = "yes" ] || [ "$th" = "Yes" ]; then
...
if [ "$th" = "no" ] || [ "$th" = "No" ]; then
```

Or:

```
if [ "$th" = "yes" -o "$th" = "Yes" ]; then
...
if [ "$th" = "no" -o "$th" = "No" ]; then
```

Or, if you are using `bash` as a Bourne shell interpreter:

```
if [ "${th,,}" = "yes" ]; then
...
if [ "${th,,}" = "no" ]; then
```

(`${th,,}` being substituted with the lower case value of variable `th`)

Comment: oh man I didnt even notice that, I have been at this script since 3:30 eastern time.  So I changed it and it works but the last echo that says "Coming right up." prints along with the echo when I say no.  Which would be the last variable in the second if

Comment: is there anything you would recommend for me to read or research on for scripting language that may help in the future?

Comment: To answer your first comment: if you say No, then the `else` statement is executed, that's normal. You should put your `if [ "$th" = "water" ]...fi` block inside the `if [ "$th" = "yes" ]...fi` block. And no, sorry, my bedside book is the `bash` manual, but that's not the most didactic reading. The answers here are a good reading though.

Comment: @E.Mart For reading you can check this one: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ and also stack overflow documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/topics

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it.  Ill definitely look into that, scripting is no joke lol.

Answer (score 2):

Your tests aren't doing what you think they're doing.

```
if [ "$var" = "value" ] || [ "Value" ];
```

This does not do two equality tests.  It checks the first case, and then, if that fails, checks to see whether `"Value"` exists, which it does, because it is there to check.  So it always passed through to the `then` corresponding with the `if`.  You probably want:

```
if [ "$var" = value" ] || [ "$var" = "Value" ]
```

Better still might be to look into a `case..esac` block:

```
case "$var" in
    value|Value)
        do_stuff
        ;;
    other|Other)
        do_something_else
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: is there anything you would recommend for me to read or research on for scripting language that may help in the future?

Comment: I would definitely recommend http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Answer (score 0):

(1) When you test for `[ "Yes" ]` and later for `[ "No" ]`, you need to still compare it against `th` in both parts:

`[ "$th" = "yes" ] || [ "$th" = "Yes" ]`

and

`[ "$th" = "no" ] || [ "$th" = "No" ]`

(2) For the section, `if [ "$th" = "yes" ] || [ "$th" = "Yes" ];` , you need to extend this code block to include everything up to the test for `No` and use an `elif` at that point to combine it as one larger compound `if-elif-fi` statement.

Here it is with the corrections mentioned above:

```
echo -n "Are you thirsty?"
read th

if [ "$th" = "yes" ] || [ "$th" = "Yes" ]; then

    echo "What would you like to drink?"
    read th

    if [ "$th" = "water" ]; then
      echo "Clear crisp and refreshing."
    elif [ "$th" = "beer" ]; then
      echo "Let me see some ID."
    elif [ "$th" = "wine" ]; then
      echo "One box or Two?"
    else
      echo "Coming right up."
    fi

elif [ "$th" = "no" ] || [ "$th" = "No" ]; then
    echo "Come back when you are thirsty."
fi
```